# Variance of a random variable with a uniform distribution evaluated starting from the moment generating function

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution, variance, moment-generating-functions

I'd like to get the variance of a random variable $X$ with an uniform distribution over the interval $(a, b)$ starting from the moment generating function $MGF_X$. The variance is:

$$
Var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2
$$

The $MGF_X(t)$ is:

$$
MGF_X(t) = \frac{e^{t \, b}  - e^{t \, a}}{t \, (b - a)}
$$

The first derivative is (it's reported also on [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformDistribution.html#:%7E:text=(7)-,The%20moment-generating%20function,wolfram.com%2FUniformDistribution.html,-Wolfram%20Web%20Resources)):

$$
MGF'_X(t) = \frac{b \, e^{t \, b} - a \, e^{t \, a}} {t \, (b - a)} - \frac{e^{t \, b} - e^{t \, a}} {t^2 \, (b - a)}
$$

The expected value of $X$ is (I got it starting from the $MGF_X(t)$; I evaluated the limit for $t \rightarrow 0$ of the first derivative of the $MGF_X(t)$):

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} MGF'_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{a + b}{2}
$$

Now I need to apply the following one in order to get $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$:

$$
\left( \frac{d^2}{dt^2} MGF_X(t) \right) \Bigr|_{\substack{t = 0}} = \mathbb{E} [X^2]
$$

I got the following result:

$$
MGF''_X(t) = \frac{b^2 \, e^{t \, b} - a^2 \, e^{t \, a}}{t \, (b -a)}
$$

In $t=0$ the result is infinity; this is strange, what mistake did I make?

I tried also the evaluated the limit for $t \rightarrow 0$ of the second derivative and I got:

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} MGF''_X(t) = \frac{3 \, b^3 - 3 \, a^3 + a^2 \, b - a \, b^2}{4 \, (b-a)}
$$

Comment: The end result is not infinity for $t=0$. Have you checked your computation of $MGF''_X$?

Comment: Hello @nejimban why?

Comment: 2nd derivative of the MGF (for $t\ne 0$) doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second derivative of the moment generating function is:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} MGF_X(t) &=
\frac{b^2 \, e^{b \, t} - a^2 \, e^{a \, t}} {t \, (b - a)} -
\frac{b \, e^{b \, t} - a \, e^{a \, t}} {t^2 \, (b - a)} -
\left(
\frac{b \, e^{b \, t} - a \, e^{a \, t}} {t^2 \, (b - a)} -
\frac{2 \, \left( e^{b \, t} - e^{a \, t} \right)}{t^3 \, (b - a)}
\right) =
\\
&=
\frac{b^2 \, e^{b \, t} - a^2 \, e^{a \, t}} {t \, (b - a)} -
\frac{2 \, \left( b \, e^{b \, t} - a \, e^{a \, t} \right)} {t^2 \, (b - a)} +
\frac{2 \, \left( e^{b \, t} - e^{a \, t} \right)}{t^3 \, (b - a)}
\\
&=
\frac{
t^2 \, \left( b^2 \, e^{b \, t} - a^2 \, e^{a \, t} \right) -
2 \, t \, \left( b \, e^{b \, t} - a \, e^{a \, t} \right) +
2 \, \left( e^{b \, t} - e^{a \, t} \right)
}
{
t^3 \, (b - a)
}
\\
&=
\frac{
t^2 \, b^2 \, e^{b \, t} - t^2 \, a^2 \, e^{a \, t} -
2 \, t \, b \, e^{b \, t} - 2 \, t \, a \, e^{a \, t} +
2 \, e^{b \, t} - 2 \, e^{a \, t}
}
{
t^3 \, (b - a)
}
\\
&=
\frac{
e^{b \, t} \, \left( t^2 \, b^2 - 2 \, t \, b + 2 \right) -
e^{a \, t} \, \left( t^2 \, a^2 - 2 \, t \, a + 2 \right)
}
{
t^3 \, (b - a)
}
\end{align}
$$

The limit for $t$ tending to zero is (I will apply the Hopital theorem):

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X^2] &= \lim_{t \to 0} MGF''_X(t) = \\
&=
\lim_{t \to 0}
\left(
\frac{\frac{d}{dt} e^{b \, t} \, \left( t^2 \, b^2 - 2 \, t \, b + 2 \right) -
e^{a \, t} \, \left( t^2 \, a^2 - 2 \, t \, a + 2 \right)}
{\frac{d}{dt} t^3 \, (b - a)}
\right) = \\
&=
\lim_{t \to 0}
\left(
\frac{
b \, e^{b \, t} \, \left( t^2 \, b^2 - 2 \, t \, b + 2 \right) +
e^{b \, t} \, \left( 2 \, t \, b^2 - 2 \, b \right) -
a \, e^{a \, t} \, \left( t^2 \, a^2 - 2 \, t \, a + 2 \right) -
e^{a \, t} \, \left( 2 \, t \, a^2 - 2 \, a \right)
}
{
3 \, t^2 \, (b - a)
} 
\right) =
\\
&=
\lim_{t \to 0}
\left(
\frac{
e^{b \, t} \, \left( t^2 \, b^3 - 2 \, t \, b^2 + 2 \, b + 2 \, t \, b^2 - 2 \, b \right) -
e^{a \, t} \, \left( t^2 \, a^3 - 2 \, t \, a^2 + 2 \, a + 2 \, t \, a^2 - 2 \, a \right)
}
{
3 \, t^2 \, (b - a)
} 
\right) =
\\
&=
\lim_{t \to 0}
\left(
\frac{
e^{b \, t} \, t^2 \, b^3 -
e^{a \, t} \, t^2 \, a^3
}
{
3 \, t^2 \, (b - a)
} 
\right) =
\\
&=
\lim_{t \to 0}
\left(
\frac{
e^{b \, t} \, b^3 -
e^{a \, t} \, a^3
}
{
3 \, (b - a)
} 
\right) =
\\
&=
\frac{
b^3 - a^3
}
{
3 \, (b - a)
} =
\\
&=
\frac{
(b - a) \, (a^2 + a \, b + b^2)
}
{
3 \, (b - a)
} =
\\
&=
\frac{
a^2 + a \, b + b^2
}
{
3
}
\end{align}
$$

The variance is:

$$
\begin{align}
Var(X) &= \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \left( \mathbb{E}[X] \right)^2 = \\
&= \frac{a^2 + a \, b + b^2}{3} -
\frac{(b - a)^2}{4} = \\
&= \frac{4 \, a^2 + 4 \, a \, b + 4 \, b^2 - 3 \, a^2 - 6 \, a \, b - 3 \, b^2}{12} = \\
&= \frac{a^2 - 2 \, a \, b + b^2}{12} = \\
&= \frac{(b - a)^2}{12}
\end{align}
$$